Lost my coins after bought on pancakeswap
I have buy IPTOKEN token. The transition is succesful. But after receive on my wallet coins disapier from my wallet.
Anyone can help me.
This is trasnsaction
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x8a3cbfe8302481267ee1e0c65b1e69e55a985a36ea745ba261676126f411da10

There are 3 purchases and 3 sales. You still have bnb in the account, am assuming your key is not compromised. So is that the wrong hash or are you saying that you didn't sell those 3 times? All sales: https://bscscan.com/token/0x9F06c5251cEA5F8bf0cB3a89dC9B940d8F702Dde?a=0xc86810f21960c7bf7d468246614a6b6890398687 .. The sale for 18k after the purchase for 18k in your transaction posted: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xaedcc287f84074253360be5962fa8b2ce2b1322052af0d71b67a1329136d64a2

I didn't sell anything, I just bought 3 times and after some minute's tokens moved from my account. Now I have on my balance only 0.23 IPTOKEN

Ok it's a total scam, "CoinToken". Another address has allowance to move your tokens.

There's no transferFrom in the scam coin so when router tries to call it (where would normally revert for allowance issue) the token call its fallback which calls some obfuscated functions and lets it pass.

And there is no chance to get back the lost coins?

No, the bnb is being swapped out by the wallet address that added the liquidity, using your tokens (and others that purchased), while the worthless scam of a token is not even erc compliant and a contract designed only to rip people off. So I cannot see how you can extract any value from it. At least your wallet isn't compromised.

Thank you for the clarification bro..

Much love and good luck in future.
